# H-bridge, LED driver, DAC

Tags: led, driver, h-bridge, dac

I am trying to interface a circuit with an FPGA. There is an H-bridge in the circuit that is driving me crazy. The inverted RED and IR signals are coming from FPGA. The light intensity signals are coming from a DAC to control LED intensity[image].

Can someone explain how this part works? Specially why there is this FDS56892 N channel MOSFET in the design. Is't H bridge on the circuit enough to alternate the LEDs?**

Comment: This makes no sense, you don't want to use a DAC with an FET H bridge as you want the FETs to only ever be fully on or off.  Use PWM instead.

Comment: It's a bidirectional current controlled LED driver.

Answer (score 1):

The H bridge is enough to alternate the LEDs, but some mechanism needs to turn the bottom of each half-bridge off when the opposite top is on.  The "extra" NFETs do that by pulling the current command (to U1A and U1B) low.